# JOGL OpenGL - Some imports are missing

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I imported jogl jar files from the maven repository, but it seems like there are some packages that are missing. these are: `opengl.glu` and `opengl.awt`.
The version I imported is 2.1.2, but I also tried other newer versions.

```
com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU
com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas
```

So where can I import GLU and GLCanvas from?

Comment: Use either JOGL 2.3.2 (the latest stable version) or JOGL 2.4.0 (the latest release candidate). Use jogamp-fat.jar: https://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/rc/v2.4.0-rc-20200307/fat/jogamp-fat.jar Please rather post JOGL specific questions on our official forum: http://forum.jogamp.org

Comment: Ok, will post on the forum next time, but as I said I tried newer versions including 2.3.2 and it does not either contain these two packages. As for  2.4.0, it does not exists on the maven repository, thus I cannot use it on my project (my hosting does not allow including jar files manually)

Comment: Which JAR(s) did you use? JOGL 2.4.0 isn't on Maven Central because it's a release candidate, we don't publish all release candidates on Maven Central. jogamp-fat.jar contains those classes in JOGL 2.3.2. I advise you to use another hosting then as many third party libraries aren't on Maven Central.

Comment: I've just checked jogamp-fat.jar in JOGL 2.3.2 with 7zip right now and it contains GLU and GLCanvas: https://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/rc/v2.3.2/fat/jogamp-fat.jar It contains the two packages you mentioned in your original post. Note that JOGL 2.1.2 has different package names, don't confuse JOGL 2.1.2 (javax.* like JOGL 1) with JOGL 2.3.2 (com.*).

Comment: This should work: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all-main/2.3.2/jar Use our wiki next time ;)

Comment: Please can you let me know which JAR you used?

Comment: Hi, it's ok, I just download the JARs manually from the official website and it worked. But the one that didnt work for me was from the maven repository (I tried different versions too): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all-main/2.3.2

Comment: mvnrepository isn't the official source, rather use search.maven.org. You have to use jogl-all-main + gluegen-rt-main like in my engine: https://jogamp.org/cgit/ardor3d.git/tree/ardor3d-jogl/pom.xml